# how to remove relation for specific instances with sequelize / mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database, sequelize.js

I created a many-to-many association between courses and users like this:

```
Course.belongsToMany(User, { through: 'CourseUser'});
User.belongsToMany(Course, { through: 'CourseUser'});
```

which generates a join table called CourseUser.

I add a relation for a specific course and user with the following server side function that happens on the click of a button:
 the userCourse variable looks like this: { UserId: 7, CourseId: 13 }

```
  addUser: function(req, res) {
    var userCourse = req.body;
    db.CourseUser.create(userCourse).then(function () {
      res.sendStatus(200);
    });
  }
```

1. Is this the correct way of adding the association between an existing user and an existing course? (if not, what is the correct way)
2. I would like to have an ability of removing the association when clicking on another button. But I can't quite figure out how to set up the function.

Comment: Please accept my answer if it answered your question or tell me in a comment what part is still unclear to you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. If you already have a `User` and `Course` instance and are just associating them in `addUser`, then yes, this is the correct way of creating an association between them.
2. You should be able to remove this association in at least 4 ways:

1: Through `User` model:

```
User.removeCourse(courseObject);
```

2: Through `Course` model:

```
Course.removeUser(userObject);
```

3: On the `CourseUser` model, without having a `CourseUser` instance available:

```
db.CourseUser.destroy({
    where: {...}
});
```

4: Having a `CourseUser` instance available:

```
courseUser.destroy();
```

You can bind `.then` and `.catch` on all these operations to do something on success / on error.

Answer (score 2):

Your model relationship is okay:

```
Course.belongsToMany(User, { through: 'CourseUser'}); User.belongsToMany(Course, { through: 'CourseUser'});
```

and values: 
`{ UserId: 7, CourseId: 13 }`

Implementation could look thus for adding a UserCourse relationship:

```
addUser: function(req, res) {
    const { UserId, CourseId } = req.body;
    db.Course.findOne({
        where: { id: CourseId }
    }).then(course => {
        course.setUsers([UserId])
        res.sendStatus(200);
    }).catch(e => console.log(e));
}
```

while this could handle user detaching:

```
removeUser: function (req, res) {
    const { UserId, CourseId } = req.body;
    db.Course.findOne({
        where: { id: CourseId }
    }).then(course => {
        course.removeUsers([UserId])
        res.sendStatus(200);
    }).catch(e => console.log(e));
}
```

I hope this will be helpful however